# HashTable multidimensional array confusion?

Tags: c#, hashtable

A Suit is the 4 symbols in a card and suit is the 13 numbers and letters of the card.  I am confused on

```
cardsInSuit.Add(value, new PlayingCard(suit, value));
```

---

Is it saying to put value in PlayingCard(suit, value)?  And then on this.cardPack.Add(suit, cardsInSuit); Since hashTable is all linear. I am seeing this as suit = 0 and cardsInSuit is the value that points to another linear array of 0-12.  Am I Correct?.

---

```
  class Pack
{
    private Hashtable cardPack; // no need to specify
    private PlayingCard[,] cardPack;

    public Pack()
    {
        this.cardPack = new Hashtable();

        for (Suit suit = Suit.Clubs; suit <= Suit.Spades; suit++) // outer loop
        {
            SortedList cardsInSuit = new SortedList(); // sorted list makes 2 array
            for (Value value = Value.Two; value <= Value.Ace; value++)
            {
                cardsInSuit.Add(value, new PlayingCard(suit, value));
            }
            this.cardPack.Add(suit, cardsInSuit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have two fields both called `cardPack` (one is a `Hashtable` and one is a 2-D array of `PlayingCard`).  This won't compile -- did you copy the code correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it saying to put value in PlayingCard(suit, value)

No, it's adding an entry to a Map.  Both HashTable and SortedList are Maps, conceptually.  A Map is a mathematical concept.  It is a collection of key-value pairs.  Once populated, you 'give' a collection a key, and it will give you the value that corresponds to it.  You can also ask the collection for all of it's keys, or all of it's key-value pairs.

While there are a lot of things I don't like about this code, I'll try to not get sidetracked with my improvements of it.

The HashTable has a key of a suit, and a value of a SortedList.  Given the way the lists are populated, if you give the table a suit, it will give you a collection of all of the cards of that suit.

The SortedLists are populated such that they key is a card value and the value is a particular card.  There is a special PlayingCard class that holds the information about a card that you haven't shown us.  (It's definition is rather obvious, so there's no need to see it.)

So, the code segment here is all designed to populate a hashtable that has every card.  It's use would be to ask it for a suit, and then to ask the resulting collection for a value, and as a result you will be given a PlayingCard with that particular suit/value.  So you might ask the HashTable for Hearts, and then ask the resulting collection for a seven, and you will be given a PlayingCard that represents a seven of hearts.

> Since hashTable is all linear

Neither the HashTable nor the SortedList are 'linear'.  While the implementation of each class is rather interesting (and offtopic for now) it's best to think of them as entirely unordered.  (Yes, even the SortedList.)  The idea of these structures is that they will store the data however they want in order to optimize a few operations.  Those operations are adding items to the map, removing items from the map, and getting the value that corresponds to a particular key.  They each use two different algorithms for accomplishing this.  The HashTable stores a hash of the key in an array .(This is really cool, and really efficient, but also beyond the scope of this post to explain.).  The SortedList stores all of the keys in-order.  Because they are in order you can use a Binary Search algorithm to find a particular key, which is much quicker than looking through every single key until you find the right one.